# Browsing DFS share keeps moving up a folder

Tags: dfs, dfs-r, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a DFS-R namespace with three nodes. Two of the nodes work just fine, but a third node does something very strange.

When you are browsing the node through the namespace, when you change into a folder it dumps you out of the folder and back where you were moments before. Sometimes it then dumps you out of *that* folder and you watch as you work your way back up the directory tree.

I apologise for the animated gif, but it looks like this when it happens:

> [image]

1. In the `apps` node of the namespace
2. Change into the "MYOB" directory
3. After about 1 second, are dumped back in the `apps` node

What could be causing this? Node is Server 2012 R2.

Comment: I'd take a network trace. If the DFSN traffic shows referrals are returned with correct values etc, then DFSN is not the concern. You might have some explorer/shell behavior itself that needs investigation. I'd recommend a Microsoft support case in this case.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue, with Server 2012. So far I haven't been able to find a cause either but am still investigating.

Comment: @JeffMiles - interestingly, I found a rogue server in the DFS Namespace. It didn't have have any folders allocated to it, but it was at the namespace level. That server was online, but in the process of being decommissioned and nobody knew it was a DFS server. Since removing it, the problem has gone away (or at least hasn't been observed).

Answer (score 0):

By [Mark Henderson](https://serverfault.com/users/7709/mark-henderson)

Interestingly, I found a rogue server in the DFS Namespace. It didn't have have any folders allocated to it, but it was at the namespace level. That server was online, but in the process of being decommissioned and nobody knew it was a DFS server. Since removing it, the problem has gone away (or at least hasn't been observed).